# Facebook API:- Get Facebook page feeds data as per shared post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using facebook graph api I want to get shared post data as like in this image:- 
[image]

Required data is a highlight in the image.

Facebook graph api call by me is:- https://graph.facebook.com/v4.0/713630032329590/feed?summary=1&fields=engagement,id,created_time,message,full_picture,actions,attachments,from,icon,is_popular,is_published,is_spherical,place,privacy,properties,sheduled_publish_time,shares,likes,comments,status_type&access_token=EAAFIYsJbA5ABAF2KzPil7V78yBfGX1NcUv9c..

All over data is available but only complete page shared related data is not available in this api. I am not able to analyze which type of param required to get this detail.

Comment: you REALLY need to invalidate that token immediately. why would you publish an access token? do you you leave your house key in front of the door too? ;) - btw, removing it from the text is not good enough, it would still be in the history.

Comment: So you are looking for (well, actually letting others do the looking for you) this then, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post/sharedposts/ …?